# Why is the Grid Container selection only showing the first column?

Tags: css, css-grid

I know enough CSS to be dangerous but not productive. I just learned about grids.

In my image below, you'll see I have a 2 column grid set up. The left column contains a "project name". This is an li tag. The right column contains a settings gear icon. This is a span tag. These are both children of a parent div

I set the grid up on the parent div, which I have rolled over in the image below. **Why is the grid container size only the size of the first column and not the whole row?**

This is causing me confusion because I want to have a border across the whole row when I rollover the row.

[image: css grid]

My HTML (JSX):

```
<div className={styles.project}>
  <li onClick={() => props.onSelect(props.name)}>{props.name}</li>
  <span className={styles.settings}>{"\u2699"}</span>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.project {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  grid-template-areas: "name settings";
  grid-template-columns: 150px 35px;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  display: grid;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.project li:hover {
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 160px;
}

.project li {
  list-style-type: none;
  grid-area: name;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.project .settings {
  grid-area: settings;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.project .settings:hover {
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-right: -160px;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to reproduce the problem. Please add the HTML.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're highlighting the grid item not the grid container.

Comment: Yep, I was trying a few different things. Actually by posting this I think I got the solution which I will post below now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was due to the size I chose for the first grid column:

```css
grid-template-columns: 150px 35px;
```

Which is fine except I was then adding padding and margins so it pushed the second grid out.

Resolved by changing it to:

```css
grid-template-columns: auto 35px;
```

And setting my hover to

(note: In my example above I had the hover on the li tag)

```css
.project:hover {
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-width: 100%;
}
```